# How do you use beautifulsoup or some Python library to scrape or retrieve the real website URL from a redirect link? Example below:

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a redirect link here: https://www.capterra.com/external_click/category-upgraded-visit-website-button/1/1000551/194873/uc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGdpLmNvbS9nb3BnaS91Y2Fhcy1kZW1vLXJlcXVlc3Q*dXRtX3NvdXJjZT1jYXB0ZXJyYSZ1dG1fbWVkaXVtPWNwYyZ1dG1fY2FtcGFpZ249TkE6REc6VUNhYVNDYXB0ZXJyYSZ1dG1fY29udGVudD1MUA==?ds=356501d23992f743aad5c9481391c74d92edd624

that when you click on it, it leads you to the actual website link here: https://www.pgi.com/gopgi/ucaas-demo-request/?utm_source=capterra&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=NA:DG:UCaaSCapterra&utm_content=LP

I have thousands of other links like this, and I was wondering if there was a way I could use code to go to each re-direct link, and then get the actual website link once on the website. Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `requests` module:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('your redirect link')
print(r.url) # this prints the actual website link after redirection
```

### NOTE

Don't forget to install `requests` module using `pip install resqests` in the command line

Comment: Yes, thank you this worked. I had to specify a header in requests as well as add verify = false. Like this: hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, url = 'your redirect link', and then r = requests.get(url, headers = hdr, verify = False), print(r.url).